# How to add multiple pages in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a login and registration page for a web application.  I have been using this tutorial:

> https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial

However, I want to modify it so everything is not in the same index.ejs file (I do not just want to use "include") but rather on a separate page entirely.  In order to do this,  I created a register-login.ejs file and a register-login.js file in addition to the index.js file.  In my "register-login.js" file I added:

```
`router.get('/register-login', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('register-login');
});
```

`
Then in my app.js file I added:

```
var routes = require('./routes/register-login');app.use('/register-login', routes);
```

Unfortunately, this attempt results in a 404 Error.  How do I properly separate the provided code in the above tutorial into two separate pages: index.js and register-login.js, index.ejs and register-login.ejs and connect them properly?

Answer (score 1):

register extra routes on the router.

```
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('./views/register');
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('./views/login');
});
```

then use them all with `app.use('/', router);`or `app.use(require('./routes/user'));` if you export the router and require it

Comment: That is exactly what I have except you decided to use two files: login.ejs and register.ejs; instead of my one login-register.ejs.  How would that fix the problem?

Comment: sorry I dont understand the question then, since it said you get a 404, using the routes this way you should get 2 routes that you can access

Comment: Oh, I see your misunderstanding, I edited the above question to help clarify my question